# Basic syntax question for shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I am new to the shared_ptr. I have a few questions regarding the syntax of C++0x shared_ptr as below:

```
//first question
shared_ptr<classA>ptr(new classA()); //works
shared_ptr<classA>ptr;
ptr = ?? //how could I create a new object to assign it to shared pointer?


//second question
shared_ptr<classA>ptr2; //could be tested for NULL from the if statement below
shared_ptr<classA> ptr3(new classA());
ptr3 = ?? //how could I assign NULL again to ptr3 so that the if statement below becomes true?

if(!ptr3) cout << "ptr equals null";
```

Answer (score 10):

```
shared_ptr<classA> ptr;
ptr = shared_ptr<classA>(new classA(params));
// or:
ptr.reset(new classA(params));
// or better:
ptr = make_shared<classA>(params);

ptr3 = shared_ptr<classA>();
// or
ptr3.reset();
```

Edit: Just to summarize why `make_shared` is preferred to an explicit call to `new`:

1. Some (all?) implementation use one memory allocation for the object constructed and the counter/deleter. This increases performance.
2. It's exception safe, consider a function taking two shared_ptrs:

   ```
   f(shared_ptr<A>(new A), shared_ptr<B>(new B));
   ```

   Since the order of evaluation is not defined, a possible evaluation may be: construct A, construct B, initialize `share_ptr<A>`, initialize `shared_ptr<B>`. If B throws, you'll leak A.
3. Separation of responsibility. If `shared_ptr` is responsible for deletion, make it responsible for the allocation too.

Comment: Why is make_shared better here?

Comment: @Fred: Separation of responsibility. `make_shared<>` allows the library to handle the `new`, so your code doesn't display an apparently unbalanced `new` invocation. The library does the `delete`, so it should do the `new` also.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: `make_shared` can potentially eliminate one allocation.

Comment: Steven T. Lavavej dropped in one of his talks on the STL (IIRC) that the VC10 std::make_shared<> allocates both the memory and the counter in the same request, which not only provides one fewer allocations, but also a locality of reference that is a potential optimisation.

Comment: @Kaz, @Fred: Yep, boost does it too: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html Actually they mention also the exception safety which I forgot. So there are 3 reasons to use make_shared where possible.

Comment: @Karl: That's a pointless view of the code that only serves to create needless worry.  The allocation is balanced on the very same line by assigning to the smart pointer, and this is how people have been using auto_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, and others for over a decade — it's the essence of RAII.  ybungalobill and Kaz point out real advantages.

Answer (score 0):

try `ptr3.reset(NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

> how could I create a new object to
>   assign it to shared pointer?

You have to "reset" the shared pointer :

```
classA* my_pointer = new classA();
shared_ptr<classA>ptr;
ptr.reset( my_pointer );
```

> how could I assign NULL again to ptr3
>   so that the if statement below becomes
>   true?

Again, by using reset but with no argument( or null)

```
ptr3.reset();
```